# Segmentation fault passing struct pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm pretty newb in C and in order to learn about structs I'm building a program which provides a limited set of functionality for a *struct ll_string* which basically is a linkedlist of strings.

The set of functions I'm trying to implement includes an *insert_ll_string()* function which should concanate a passed in *struct ll_string* element to the end of another *struct ll_string* element but fails to do so because the moment the function is called in my test cases, the program crashes with a sig fault. This is at the *STILL WORKS* and *SIG FAULT* comments of the *test_insert()* function.

This is its header file:

file: **ll_string.h**

```
struct ll_string {
    char *string;
    struct ll_string *next;
};

struct ll_string *create_ll_string(char *, struct ll_string *);
void insert_ll_string(struct ll_string *, struct ll_string *);
void remove_item_from_ll_string(struct ll_string *, struct ll_string *);
void free_ll_string(struct ll_string *);
void print_ll_string(struct ll_string *);
```

and this is it's corresponding *.c* file missing a few definitions for functions declared in *ll_string.h*, but I guess my problem probably only revolves around the functions *create_ll_string()* and *insert_ll_string()* anyways.

file: **ll_string.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ll_string.h"

/* create_ll_string: allocates memory for a new struct ll_string and 
 * initializes it with given arguments returns a pointer to new struct */
struct ll_string *create_ll_string(char *string, struct ll_string *next) {
    struct ll_string *new_ll_string;

    if (!string) {
        printf("string can\'t be NULL\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (*string == '\0') {
        printf("string needs to be at least 1 char long\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!(new_ll_string = (struct ll_string *) malloc(sizeof(struct ll_string)))) {
        printf("couldn\'t allocate mem for new ll_string\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    new_ll_string->string = strdup(string);
    new_ll_string->next = next;

    return new_ll_string;
}

/* insert_ll_string: concanates item to the end of dest */
void insert_ll_string(struct ll_string *dest, struct ll_string *item) {
    struct ll_string *cur;

    if (!dest) {
        printf("dest and item can\'t be NULL\n");
        return;
    }
    if (!item) {
        printf("item can\'t be NULL\n");
        return;
    }

    cur = dest;
    while (!cur->next) {
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    cur->next = item;

    return ;
}

/* remove_item_from_ll_string: removes item from list src */
void remove_item_from_ll_string(struct ll_string *src, struct ll_string *item) {
    return ;
}

/* printf_ll_string: prints each string in ll_string */
void print_ll_string(struct ll_string *ll_string) {
    if (!ll_string) {
        printf("ll_string is NULL\n");
        return ;
    }

    do {
        printf("%s\n", ll_string->string);
    } while (!(ll_string = ll_string->next));
}

/* free_ll_string: frees all memory pointed to by ll_string */
void free_ll_string(struct ll_string *ll_string) {
    struct ll_string *next;

    if (!ll_string) {
        return ;
    }

    while ((next = ll_string->next)) {
        free(ll_string->string);
        free(ll_string);
        ll_string = next;
    }
}
```

and here are my tests. Everything works fine until *insert_ll_struct()* is evoked by the *test_insert()* function. (*test_create()* works as expected) Tests are done using the [MinUnit](http://www.jera.com/techinfo/jtns/jtn002.html) framework.

file: **tests_ll_string.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "minunit.h"

#include "ll_string.h"

#define MAX_ERROR_MSG_LENGTH 1000

int tests_run = 0;

static char *test_create(void) {
    struct ll_string *test_ll;
    struct ll_string *test_null_ll;
    char *empty_string = strdup("");
    char *null_string = NULL;
    char *correct_string = strdup("this should work");
    char *correct_string2 = strdup("this should also work");
    char *error_msg;

    if (!(error_msg = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_ERROR_MSG_LENGTH))) {
        printf("couldn\'t allocate mem for error msg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // test_ll->string == correct_string
    // test_ll->next == NULL
    test_ll = create_ll_string(correct_string, NULL);
    sprintf(error_msg, "error, test_ll->string != \"%s\" is %s", correct_string, test_ll->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(test_ll->string, correct_string) == 0);

    // test_ll->next->string == correct_string
    // test_ll->string == correct_string2
    test_ll = create_ll_string(correct_string2, test_ll);
    sprintf(error_msg, "error, test_ll->string != \"%s\" is %s", correct_string2, test_ll->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(test_ll->string, correct_string2) == 0);

    sprintf(error_msg, "error, test_ll->next->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", correct_string, test_ll->next->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(test_ll->next->string, correct_string) == 0);

    test_null_ll = test_ll;
    test_null_ll = create_ll_string(empty_string, test_ll);
    // test_null_ll == NULL
    mu_assert(
            "error, test_null_ll != NULL",
            test_null_ll == NULL);

    test_null_ll = test_ll;
    test_null_ll = create_ll_string(null_string, test_ll);
    // test_null_ll == NULL
    mu_assert(
            "error, test_null_ll != NULL",
            test_null_ll == NULL);

    sprintf(error_msg, "error, test_ll->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", correct_string2, test_ll->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(test_ll->string, correct_string2) == 0);

    sprintf(error_msg, "error, test_ll->next->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", correct_string, test_ll->next->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(test_ll->next->string, correct_string) == 0);

    free_ll_string(test_ll);
    free(correct_string);
    free(correct_string2);
    free(empty_string);
    free(error_msg);

    return 0;
}

static char *test_insert(void) {
    struct ll_string *ll_test1;
    struct ll_string *ll_test2;
    struct ll_string *ll_test3;

    char *test_string1 = strdup("test_string1");
    char *test_string2 = strdup("test_string2");
    char *test_string3 = strdup("test_string3");
    char *error_msg;

    if (!(error_msg = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_ERROR_MSG_LENGTH))) {
        printf("couldn\'t allocate mem for error msg");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    ll_test1 = create_ll_string(test_string1, NULL);
    ll_test2 = create_ll_string(test_string2, NULL);
    ll_test3 = create_ll_string(test_string3, NULL);

    // STILL WORKS

    insert_ll_string(ll_test1, ll_test2); // SEG FAULT
    insert_ll_string(ll_test1, ll_test3);

    sprintf(error_msg, "error, ll_test1->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", test_string1, ll_test1->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(ll_test1->string, test_string1) == 0);
    sprintf(error_msg, "error, ll_test1->next->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", test_string2, ll_test1->next->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(ll_test1->next->string, test_string2) == 0);
    sprintf(error_msg, "error, ll_test1->next->next->string != \"%s\" is \"%s\"", test_string1, ll_test1->next->next->string);
    mu_assert(
            error_msg,
            strcmp(ll_test1->next->next->string, test_string3) == 0);

    free_ll_string(ll_test1);
    free_ll_string(ll_test2);
    free_ll_string(ll_test3);
    free(test_string1);
    free(test_string2);
    free(test_string3);

    return 0;
}

static char *all_tests(void) {
    mu_run_test(test_create);
    mu_run_test(test_insert);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *result = all_tests();
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
    } else {
        printf("ALL TESTS PASSED\n");
    }
    printf("Tests run: %d\n", tests_run);

    return result != 0;
}
```

and this is the output of compilation and execution:

```
>> gcc -Wall -o test ll_string.c tests_ll_string.c
>> ./test
string needs to be at least 1 char long
string can't be NULL
[1]    6789 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./test
```

What's causing this Sigmentation fault? I'm not accessing any memory besides local variables in the section the program crashes. I'm not dereferencing the pointers I'm passing to *insert_ll_struct()* at least not immediately after the function has been evoked.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Use a debugger  - it will tell you where the seg fault occurs

Comment: Or compile with debug info and run under `valgrind`.

Comment: do you get the seg fault if you just run test_insert (i.e. disable test_create)

Comment: I was thinking about testing it with gdb but I still need to figure out how to use it yet but now is probably the right time to learn it. :) In the meantime I would still appreciate any answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is staring us in the face. In `insert_ll_string()` :

```
while (!cur->next) {
```

should be

```
while (cur->next) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the logic in `free_ll_string()`. Are you sure you aren't freeing memory twice? In the code it looks like if frees up all strings in the chain. Therefore I think you will free `test_ll` multiple times in `test_create`. See if you still get the error when disabling `test_create`, and if not then you issue I think is probably resulting from undefined behaviour because you are free-ing things more than once...

It is good practice to set any freed pointer to NULL after freeing the memory that it is pointing to, then you will avoid this problem.

```
/* free_ll_string: frees all memory pointed to by ll_string */
void free_ll_string(struct ll_string *ll_string) {
    struct ll_string *next;

    if (!ll_string) {
        return ;
    }

    while ((next = ll_string->next)) {
        free(ll_string->string);
        free(ll_string);
        ll_string = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The seg fault also occurs when I just run test_insert. I can't see me freeing memory twice. The free_ll_string function should free all strings in the linked list starting from the passed in element till the end of the list and should then free each struct as well.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe not the cause of this seg fault then, since `test_null__ll` is `NULL`, nor do you attempt to call `free_ll_string` on it. However, there is still a danger here I think: If you `A = create ll_string("a", NULL)` and then `B = create_ll_string("b", A)`, then freeing `B` will free `A`, and then freeing `B` will free `B` again. This is because `next` is not duplicated in `create_ll_string` and/or the pointers are not set to `NULL` in `free_ll_string`. So, if a programmer is diligent in calling `free_ll_string` for each `create_ll_string` statement, they are going to hit this problem.

Comment: (In fact, setting the pointers to NULL in `free_ll_string` wouldnt help in this case, but it is good defensive style anyway)

Comment: Also calling `A = create_ll_string("a", NULL)` then `free_ll_string(A)` wont free anything, since `while ((next = ll_string->next))` performs no iterations.

Comment: Ok. I rewrote parts of `create_ll_string` and `free_ll_string`. Here are the new versions: [Gist][https://gist.github.com/muchosteechos/04834bd351102cae53a2683dc8866a4f]

Comment: Ok. I rewrote parts of `create_ll_string` and `free_ll_string`. Here are the new versions: https://gist.github.com/muchosteechos/04834bd351102cae53a2683dc8866a4f
Now `create_ll_string` copies a passed in `ll_string next` if it's not `NULL` and `free_ll_string` now works on pointers of pointers `struct ll_string **`. You have to call `free_ll_string(&ptr_to_ll_struct)` now which then also sets `ptr_to_ll_struct = NULL`. Also I have looked into the `while ((next = ll_string->next))` and rewrote it to `do { } while ((next = ll_string->next));` which should work properly now.

Comment: Also I found the bug that was causing the seg fault. It was the loop inside `insert_ll_string` that should've been tested as `while (cur->next) { ... }` instead of `while (!cur->next) { ... }`. But thank you anyways your comments were very helpful aswell! Edit: Oops seems like you found it first ;)

Answer (score 0):

while (!cur->next) { cur = cur->next; }
This code will cause crash suppose cur->next return null than you are trying to acess null next that is invalid you should put null check for cur in  while loop like thiswhile (null!=cur&& !cur->next)